# How to go to next block of else if upon certain condition in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Say i have conditions setup like this:

```
if (condition1) {
    for (var i in objx) { 
       if (objx[i] == 3) {
         //go to next else if
       }
     }
} else if(condition2) {
   ...
}
```

so there are two ways it should reach to condition2 if statement:

1. when condition1 is false
2. something inside loop isn't as needed.

i could have put whole if else inside loop but there are more conditions and this will just make code harder to read and follow. Secondly, i considered to finally try out goto and label method, but according to someone that according to this http://es5.github.io/#x12.12 goto will be obsolete.

**Ideally:** I'd have preferred a way to use break, and continue somehow in if else statements.

Comment: Put the code in a function and call it when you need it.

Comment: The only possible way of doing this would be a **GOTO** statement I suppose but that is considered as bad programming practice. If you could elaborate your objective a little more then we could suggest you alternatives.

Comment: @Pointy I guess he wants to keep the code as it is and just transfer the control.

Comment: I'm quite interested in a practical use for such a logic block, because if you didn't need to jump from the inner you would've done what @Ori Drori answered and moved the bool outside the ifelse block.

Comment: thefourtheye solution will work for now but i think it wont scale. and what ori Dori did can scale it's hard to follow the logic just by glancing. For example, if you take what i'm doing at top it's pretty easy to see what should happen, **if cond1 then check if certain condition is also true , if either one of them is not then just go to cond2 and try that**

Comment: i guess this is how i would say something to someone in real life. Clean the door and to find the cleaning supplies Check out Room 256, if it's not locked, among drawers of the third closet and if still dont find it then just go to 11th floor and ask janitor.

Comment: this is what i am doing: if there is data in local storage search through it, see if any of it's too outdated, if not then return this, otherwise if it's outdated and or if there is no data in local storage prepare to make ouath request and get data.

Answer (score 2):

Use a flagging variable, like this

```
// Initial value is `true` because, if `condition1` is falsy, we still have to
// evaluate `condition2` by default.
var flag = true;

if (condition1) {
  // `condition1` is truthy, skip `condition2`
  flag = false;

  for (var i in objx) {
    if (objx[i] == 3) {
      // We need to check the second condition
      flag = true;
      // skip rest of the loop
      break;
    }
  }
}

// Evaluate condition2 only if `flag` is set
if (flag && condition2) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: last if should be `if ((flag || condition2) && !condition1)`

Comment: @GUL If `condition1` is truthy, the `flag` will be already `false`.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly other solution with `switch` :

```
switch (true) {
    case condition1:
        var doBreak = true;
        for (var i in objx) { 
            if (objx[i] == 3) {
                // go to condition2
                doBreak = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (doBreak) {
            break;
        }
    case condition2:
        // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't go from one if (else if) block to another, but you can move the internal check to the 1st if. condition1 && conditionFunc(objx) - means that if condition1 is true, run the func, and if it is true as well do this if block, if not it will move to the next else if.

```
function conditionFunc(objx) {
  for (var i in objx) {
    if (objx[i] == 3) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

if (condition1 && conditionFunc(objx)) {

} else if (condition2) {
  ...
}
```